# How can used physical memory exceed sum of 'resident' memory reported by processes?

Tags: linux, memory

Given the output of `top` shown below (which shows *all* processes currently active): how is it possible that this virtual server reports ~500M physical memory as used (used - cached, verified by `free`), while the sum of 'RES' is much lower than that? Shouldn't the sum of `RES` always exceed the used physical memory? What could the memory be in use for and by what?

```
top - 08:43:23 up 75 days,  5:00,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.08, 0.04
Tasks:  29 total,   1 running,  28 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2400000k total,   713792k used,  1686208k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   200764k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                           
    1 root      20   0 19232  544  384 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.08 init                                                                                                                              
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/201208                                                                                                                   
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/2012080                                                                                                                   
  323 pdns-rec  20   0  169m 2980 1152 S  0.0  0.1   1:58.98 pdns_recursor                                                                                                                     
  560 root      20   0  6160  200  196 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 portreserve                                                                                                                       
  578 dbus      20   0 21536  324  284 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                       
  598 nobody    20   0 17040 2108  880 S  0.0  0.1   4:48.33 openvpn                                                                                                                           
  607 nobody    20   0 16124 1112  724 S  0.0  0.0   0:41.54 openvpn                                                                                                                           
 1347 root      20   0 78732  592  508 S  0.0  0.0   0:12.35 master                                                                                                                            
 1355 postfix   20   0 78984  612  516 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.63 qmgr                                                                                                                              
 1515 root      20   0  9232  564  396 S  0.0  0.0   0:39.69 gam_server                                                                                                                        
11077 root      16  -4 10648  272  268 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd                                                                                                                             
12912 root      20   0  168m  57m 3040 S  0.0  2.4   0:56.31 puppetd                                                                                                                           
13187 root      20   0 11308 1224 1220 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 mysqld_safe                                                                                                                       
13295 mysql     20   0 1348m  44m 4232 S  0.0  1.9 246:49.61 mysqld                                                                                                                            
13391 root      20   0 66608  516  404 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                                                              
13411 root      20   0 20468  740  644 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.71 crond                                                                                                                             
13452 root      20   0  243m 1428  820 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.36 rsyslogd                                                                                                                          
16087 app       20   0 14896 1096  880 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 top                                                                                                                               
18993 newrelic  20   0 25764  124   84 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nrsysmond                                                                                                                         
18994 newrelic  20   0  103m 1540 1036 S  0.0  0.1   0:46.22 nrsysmond                                                                                                                         
23268 postfix   20   0 81356 3384 2508 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 pickup                                                                                                                            
29550 root      20   0  387m 3516 1088 S  0.0  0.1   2:25.48 fail2ban-server                                                                                                                   
31434 root      20   0 96264 2408 2376 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                                                              
31438 user      20   0 96264  816  640 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.25 sshd                                                                                                                              
31439 user      20   0  105m 1264 1260 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 bash                                                                                                                              
31456 root      20   0  165m 1768 1764 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sudo                                                                                                                              
31457 root      20   0  138m 1020 1016 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 su                                                                                                                                
31458 app       20   0 13440 3332 1492 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.07 bash
```

Note: what I'm asking is exactly the reverse of what people are commonly asking.

Requested `cat /proc/memoinfo`:

```
MemTotal:        2400000 kB
MemFree:         1682660 kB
Cached:           202948 kB
Active:           132988 kB
Inactive:         180704 kB
Active(anon):      19668 kB
Inactive(anon):    91076 kB
Active(file):     113320 kB
Inactive(file):    89628 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        110744 kB
Shmem:              2568 kB
Slab:            2268056 kB
SReclaimable:    2260740 kB
SUnreclaim:         7316 kB
```

I believe the virtualization technology is Virtuozzo.

Comment: Post the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`. Also the type of virtualization you are using.

Comment: Virtuozzo does some gymnastics with memory which means you're not ever going to get a good result. For example, according to /proc/meminfo you're using 2268056 out of 2400000 Kb of slab memory. Seeing as that isn't the case I dont think  your /proc/meminfo is that reliable. You'll need to speak to your virtual hosting provider to know how they account the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically related to VMs, RAM-usage looks different when you're "*outside, looking in*" versus "*inside, looking around*"

**Why does a VM report ~500 MB used but `top` shows much less RAM in-use?**

If the VM is reporting ~500 MB used (in the VM manager, I'm assuming), yet the total of `RES` is much lower, that's expected.

A VM (be it a VMware, Virtuozzo container, Hyper-V, or Solaris Zone) consumes more RAM than just what it's processes use.  The "overhead" needed to actually run the VM is lumped-in with that metric (virtual device-mappings, virtual device caches (such as network & disk), kernel space, etc)

For completeness sake, I'm going to provide a brief explanation of the "opposite" problem most people ask (which is how I found this question)

**Top's "Resident Set" size (`RES`) "bigger" than Physical Memory**

Resident Set size is calculated by the kernel as the sum of "anonymous" (`MM_ANONPAGES`) pages and "file-backed" (`MM_FILEPAGES`) pages. Since a single page might be counted multiple times (attributed to multiple processes), this explains why `RES` in `top` is calculated from every running process, it looks like it's consuming more memory than possible.